# Tomcat session-timeout response?

Tags: session, tomcat, struts2, timeout, interceptor

I have app works on tomcat. App is build in Struts2.

When session not contain user object ( session expired, user logout etc. ) I have interceptor which redirect user to the `loginPage`.

This works fine when Im sending standard `HttpRequest` (debugger breaks on my interceptor).

But when session expired ( I set 1 min for tests in web.xml) and I send ajax request
tomcat response is error page ( HttpRequest redirect user to login page ).

And when users of my app do some ajax requests they have error page

Does tomcat check the type of request header when session expired ?

Comment: Are the AJAX requests under the same Interceptor Stack containing your Custom Interceptor ? Check package, namespaces, etc...

Comment: Do you want the Ajax requests to still function when the session has timed out?

Comment: Does the ajax request use the session?

Comment: Ajax request's should works as normal request and required user object in session (when session expired i try to handle this request and send custom response to user ,but tomcat send error page )

Comment: What error, could you post the stacktrace?